# jquery jqmodal asp.net button have to click twice

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqmodal

Ok, newish to jQuery and need to know what I have done wrong.

I am using jqModal to show a report dialog box of data recovered from an SQL Server database.

I started from the examples from the website and all is working perfectly, but.

If I set the CssClass field of the button to jqModal (I assume this is used by jQModel to cause execution of jQModal code), then the code behind button click method is not called, but if do not set the CssClass field until the end of the button click method, then the code behind is fired, but I have to click the button again for the modal dialog to show.

The buttons are dynamically added to a table to show errors within the system. On clicking the button, the modal dialog is going to show more details about the error.

Most infuriatingly, if I click on a different record to the first, then the data for record is displayed.

So basically, my question is, how do you cause the qgModal code to fire from a code behind when the button is clicked?

OK so here is some code to explain the above.

```
<h2>Header Section</h2>
<title></title>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jqModal.js"></script>
<script>
    $().ready(function () {
        $('#dialog').jqm({ modal: true });
    });
</script>
<link href="../Content/themes/jqModal.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
    .jqmWindow {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 17%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -300px;
        width: 600px;
        background-color: #EEE;
        color: #333;
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 12px;
    }

    .jqmOverlay { background-color: #000; }

    /* Fixed posistioning emulation for IE6
       Star selector used to hide definition from browsers other than IE6
       For valid CSS, use a conditional include instead */
    * html .jqmWindow {
        position: absolute;
        top: expression((document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop) + Math.round(17 * (document.documentElement.offsetHeight || document.body.clientHeight) / 100) + 'px');
    }
    #img_Close
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        border: 0;
        outline: none;
       float:right;
    }
</style>

<h2>Body Section</h2>

<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <a href="#" class="jqModal">view</a>

    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" CssClass="jqModal">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="jqModal" Text="Label"></asp:Label>


    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  Text="Button" />

    <div class="jqmWindow" id="dialog">
        <a href="#" class="jqmClose">
            <asp:Image ID="img_Close" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/close_window-small.png" />
        </a>
        <div id="JustTesting">
            <p id="test" runat="server"></p>
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <em>READ ME</em> -->
        This is a "vanilla plain" jqModal window. Behavior and appeareance extend far beyond this.
        The demonstrations on this page will show off a few possibilites. I recommend walking
        through each one to get an understanding of jqModal <em>before</em> using it.
        <br />
        <hr />
    </div>
</form>
```

Effectively this is direct copy of the examples on the website for jqModal.

If you click on anything with the class set as jqModal then the modal window works. If you notice the asp:button does not have the CssClass option set, but if you do set it that works too.

So I have this in my code behind:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        test.InnerText = "Hello.."
        Button1.CssClass = "jqModal"
End Sub
```

As you can see all it does is update the p tag in the JustTesting Div with Hello, then sets the CssClass to jqModal.

When you click the button, nothing happens, but click it again and the modal windows is fired.

It obviously has something to do with the setting of the class which causes jqModal to fire.

Also, I have tried setting the CssClass in the page_load and this is basically the same as setting it in the html. The code behind is not called, but the modal window work fine.

I hope this is a better explanation than the first attempt.

Answer (score 0):

To cure the problem, I just stopped using jqModal